# join function with 'in' finding two values

Tags: mysql

I have the current sql statement:

```
SELECT count(distinct s.SupplierID)
from Products p join Categories c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
join Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID and c.CategoryName 
IN ('Beverages', 'Seafood');
```

I am having difficulty trying to get it to only show both beverages and seafood and not just one or the other.

Comment: please give me some sample data to give you perfect solution.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: so you only want to show suppliers who provide both seafood and beverages?

Answer (score 0):

You can use all operator to accomplish ur requirement

```
SELECT count(distinct s.SupplierID)
from Products p join Categories c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
join Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID and c.CategoryName 
=All (select 'Beverages' as column 
 Union all select 'Seafood');
```

You can give two conditions separately with and

```
SELECT count(distinct s.SupplierID)
    from Products p join Categories c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
    join Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID 
Where  c.CategoryName ='Beverages' and  c.CategoryName= 'Seafood'
```

Comment: For some weird reason that doesn't work. IS there another way?

Comment: Now I have changed it try now

Comment: Yah that doesn't either. Those were the methods i previously tried

Comment: What happened is ur getting any error or the result ur getting is not fulfilled ur requirement

Comment: It's just showing there is zero in database. But, I know there is two

Comment: I added one more solution , did u check that?

Comment: Wht zero and wht two... I didn't get you

Comment: I know there is 2 rows that contain both Seafood and Beverages but, for some reason it just shows zero.

Comment: Simply select like select *  from categories where CategoryName  IN ('Beverages', 'Seafood'); with that r u getting any result

Comment: Yes I am getting the two which is odd.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the condition in the `WHERE` clause instead of as part of the join condition?  For example:

```
SELECT count(distinct s.SupplierID) 
from Products p  
join Categories c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID 
join Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID  
WHERE c.CategoryName IN ('Beverages', 'Seafood');
```

Comment: Yah that just has the same output as before

Answer (score 0):

If I assume you want a  list of suppliers which are tied to both categories...

```
SELECT S.SupplierID
FROM Products p 
INNER JOIN join Categories c 
  on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
INNER JOIN Suppliers s 
  on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID 
WHERE c.CategoryName IN ('Beverages', 'Seafood')
GROUP BY SupplierID
HAVING count(Distinct c.categoryID) = 2
```

The issue is each category is on a different row.  So we need to find those that have both rows, and not just 2 rows of beverages or seafood.  So we distinct the category Id count it and ensure both exist as the where clause limited the results to suppliers having beverages or seafood categories.

An alternative approach is to have a join for each category but that gets cumbersome with more category names.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all suppliers that have supplied both categories, you could use this:

```
SELECT count(distinct s.SupplierID)
from Products p join Categories c on p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
      join Suppliers s on s.SupplierID = p.SupplierID 
          and c.CategoryName like 'Beverages'
where exists (select * from Products where SupplierID = s.SupplierID and 
      CategoryID = (select CategoryID from Category where name like 'Seafood') )
```